# Is meat slaughtered by non-muslim halal?

Tags: non-muslim, dhabihah

Can we eat meat from animals killed by non-muslim is it halal?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For more information about this site and our model take the [tour] and check our [help]. You may find many questions on the topic of slaughtering by non-Muslims and whether or not and who's slaughtered animals flesh is considered as halal. I'm optimistic that your question actually is answered on the site. You may start by reading [Looking for ref. meat to be valid only if a Muslim or ahlu-Kitab slaughtered it](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37642/looking-for-references-for-meat-to-be-valid-only-if-a-muslim-or-ahlu-kitab-slaug)

Answer (score 3):

The meat slaughtered by non-Muslims who are not Jews and Christians is haram; for example polytheists, idolaters, atheists and apostates etc. because it is not slaughtered in Allah's name:

> حرمت عليكم ... وما أهل لغير الله به
>
> Prohibited to you are ... and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:3](https://quran.com/5/3)</sup>

> ولا تأكلوا مما لم يذكر اسم الله عليه
>
> And do not eat of that upon which the name of Allah has not been mentioned
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:121](https://quran.com/6/121)</sup>

The meat slaughtered by Jews and Christians is halal in principle:

> اليوم أحل لكم الطيبات وطعام الذين أوتوا الكتاب حل لكم
>
> This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those who were given the Scripture is lawful for you
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:5](https://quran.com/5/5)</sup>

The two major exceptions are:

- if they are apostates who adopted Judaism or Christianity, anything they slaughterer will be haram. An apostate is not from the أوتوا الكتاب, rather they are a distinct case who are not allowed to remain in their state but must revert or be executed.
- if they slaughter it in the name of someone other than God, e.g. if they dedicate it to Christ etc. More details in [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/49487/20218) answer.

**Reference:**

> الذابح الذي لا تؤكل ذبيحته وتحرم بالاتفاق: هو الكافر من غير أهل الكتاب، كالمشرك أو الوثني عابد الأصنام، والملحد الذي لا يدين بدين، والمرتد وإن تدين بدين أهل الكتاب، والزنديق
>
> The slaughterers regarding whom there is agreement that their slaughter is haram: The disbeliever who is not from the people of the scripture, such as a polytheist or worshiper of idols, and an atheist who does not have a religion, and an apostate who has adopted the religion of the people of the scripture , and the zindiq.
>
> <sup>— [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته](https://shamela.ws/book/384/2678#p5)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Christian and Jews are also Non-Muslim, but see the Quranic verse

[Quran Verse 5:5](https://quran.com/5/5)

> This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those
>   **who were given the Scripture is lawful** for you and your food is lawful
>   for them. And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among the
>   believers and chaste women from among those who were given the
>   Scripture before you, when you have given them their due compensation,
>   desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse or taking [secret]
>   lovers. And whoever denies the faith - his work has become worthless,
>   and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.

[Quran Verse 5:3](https://quran.com/5/3)

> Prohibited to you are dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine, and
>   that which has been dedicated to other than Allah, and [those animals]
>   killed by strangling or by a violent blow or by a head-long fall or by
>   the goring of horns, and those from which a wild animal has eaten,
>   except what you [are able to] slaughter [before its death]....